# ViewModel gets cleared when "do not keep activity" dev option is turned on

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

Here is my setup
1. Main Activity - Contains MainFragment
Mainfragment - Has MainFragViewModel

Repro - 
1. Turn on do not keep activities in developer setting.
2. Launch application. 
3. Press home.

Now due to our setting following activities happened as the app went into backgroud.
1. Fragment View model - onCleared()  [UNEXPECTED, Because system is killing the fragment, and app process is not killed.]
2. Fragment destroyed [Expected]
3. Main Activity destroyed - isFinishing = false (that means framework has knowledge who is killing) [Expected]
4. Application didn't get destroyed [Expected]

Now start the app again from the background apps cards. and following happened.
1. Main Acitivity - onCreate(bundle != null) [Expected. It also delivered bundle! all good]
2. Fragment created [Expected - bundle got delivered. i.e not null]
3. FragmentViewModel instance got created [UnExpected!! as the viewmodel should have survived. Because we didn't pop the fragment. It was killed by the system due to the dev setting]

This behavior breaks my design, and in order to make my apps working ok on developers phone who may turn do not keep activity. I have to save the information in Bundle!!

What am I missing? What are your possible solutions ?

Answer (score 4):

This is intentional - ViewModels are only kept over configuration changes. 'Don't keep activities' means that activities aren't going through a configuration change - they are completely destroyed and **only** their saved instance state is retained. You'll note that `isFinishing()` is **not** the right check - the correct check is `isChangingConfigurations()`, which is indeed false when the activity is being killed due to 'Don't keep activities'.

This is same type of behavior as you'd experience if your process was killed due to low memory, so you must ensure that your Fragment works when being restored from saved instance state alone.

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion would be to improve your question. The intent of your question is rather vague and what I am going to suggest makes it vague as well.

I am under the impression that you want your **`viewModel`** to survive the **`Activity's destruction/construction process`**. To do that, you have two options:

#### Use ViewModelProviders

#### Use ViewModelFactory

I would suggest to test your device's and also make sure that there are no memory constraints that are forcing the debug mode to clear the viewModel. ViewModel should not get cleared as long as the application survives or stated to be cleared explicitly.